# Coefficient of determination applied to difference in means?

Tags: correlation, estimation, mean

Assume we have one random variable X, and two groups A and B have different mean X values. Let's say we have another variable Y that has a correlation with X of 0.5.

If I wanted to estimate a Y value difference between these groups based on the X values, would I multiply the difference by 0.5, or would I multiply it by 0.25 ($R^2$) and convert that value into Y SD units?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 0.5 and convert the value into Y SD units. The difference is one dimensional, no need to do square. Loosely speaking, we have,

$$
\frac{\hat{y_0}-\bar{y}}{\sigma_y}=\rho\frac{x_0-\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}
$$

Also think of the special case when the correlation is negative, squaring would make the direction wrong.